# How to restrict the addresses in MAIL FROM?

Tags: email, postfix, spam

Good Nighttime,

I've a postfix server combined with a mysql-database for address management. There is a table mapping the users and  their mail addresses. e.g.

```
|user|mail@domain.tld|
|user|mail2@domain.tld|
```

Besides of that I've some local aliases for services, e.g. for a webforum (forum@domain.tld)

Now I want to configure postfix the following. If someone submits a mail to the mailserver, the `MAIL FROM:` header should be checked. If it contains a mail belonging to an user in the table, it should be rejected if the user is not authed. If it belongs to local alias, it should be disallowed if it is not send by localhost.

I've configured postfix the following:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, # allow local networks
        reject_unknown_hostname,
        reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
        reject_unknown_sender_domain,
        reject_sender_login_mismatch,
        permit_sasl_authenticated
```

The (virtual) aliases are configured in `alias_database` and the `virtual_alias_maps`. For bringing the mails towards the users, the username is retrieved by mysql by `virtual_mailbox_maps`.

To have a mapping on the sasl auth user to a list of mail-addresses, `smtpd_sender_login_maps` is configured towards a a query that returns all users to a corresponding mail address.

If I test those files the results work in a single case, but in combination it does not work as intended.

If I'm testing it and I'm not logged in, the a mail with `MAIL FROM: mail@domain.tld` gets rejected as expected, but a mail with `MAIL FROM: forum@domain.tld` will be delivered. If I'm authed I can use any `MAIL FROM:` header. I do not have any overwrites configured for the submission port.

How can I configure the restrictions in a way that every user can only send from a list of allowed mail addresses?

Comment: The addresses also need to be in your virtual user table.

Comment: I've omitted this information, because i've assumed that it is implicit. The local aliases are defined via various hashmaps in the ``alias_database``  and the ``virtual_alias_maps`` key, while user mails are retrieved by mysql in ``virtual_mailbox_maps``. Furthermore ``smtpd_sender_login_maps`` is a lookup to the user by the mail address

Comment: It's been my experience that assuming things is one of the best ways to run straight into a brick wall. Or worse. I would recommend that you be as specific as possible in your question about how you have Postfix set up.

Comment: Thanks for your remark, i've updated the question itself